# How do i avoid pressing enter on a popup that has a saved password in IE?

Tags: internet, internet-explorer

I go to a site using IE which has a pop-up that asks for a password, the password is saved but I have to press enter, is there a setting where I wont have to press enter?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid this popup via IE settings.

Instead of the IE password manager, I use the free [iMacros for Internet Explorer](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/) addon for my logins. Once you created the macro for your [login](http://wiki.imacros.net/First_Steps#Encrypted_web_site_passwords), it can run automatically and no further clicks are required (you can have it navigate to a sub page at the same time).

Comment: I just installed this tool - do I just record a macro? I am assuming there is a way that this macro gets executed automatically when going to the site? Or do you mean instead of going to the site via URL, go via the macro?

Comment: >Or do you mean instead of going to the site via URL, go via the macro? => Yes! The URL GOTO commmand will open the page automatically.
To record, browser to the page, and click RECORD on the iMacros tab. Then do what you normally would do (e. g. login and click links). You will see that the commands are added in the iMacros sidebar. After you are done, click stop and save the macro.